# Генетический алгоритм на Python

Tags: python, генетический-алгоритм

Всем привет, хочу поделиться генетическим-эволюционным алгоритмом на Python.
Сделан по серии Coding Train: Genetic algorithm
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zfeTw-uFCw

К сожалению на последнем символе всегда происходит зацикливание, тут видимо повезет/ не повезет. Не могу понять почему, увеличивал и общее число популяции и менял процент мутаций, к сожалению все равно один символ ищется очень долго.

Вот простой листинг моего кода:

```
class DNA(object):
    def __init__(self,string="",length=0):
        import random
        if string:
            self.string = string
            self.length = len(string)
        elif length:
            self.string = "".join([chr(random.randrange(32,122)) for x in range(length)])


class Population(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.generation = []

    def make_generation(self,word_len,cnt=1):
        self.generation = [DNA(length=word_len) for i in range(cnt)]

    def clear_generation(self):
        self.generation = []

def fit_func(goal,element):
        fit = 0
        for i in range(len(goal)):
            if element.string[i] == goal[i]:
                fit += 1
        return round(fit/len(goal),3)


def crossover(a,b):
    x1 = a.string[:len(a.string)//2]
    y1 = b.string[len(b.string)//2:]
    return DNA(string=x1+y1)

def mutate(dna):
    import random
    for i in dna.string:
        if random.randint(1,100) < 4:
            dna.string = dna.string.replace(i,chr(random.randrange(32,122)),1)

def main():
    import random
    g = "To be or not to be"
    new_pop = Population()
    new_pop.make_generation(len(g),1000)
    while True:
        good_el = {}
        for i in new_pop.generation:
            ff = fit_func(g,i)
            if i.string == g:
                print("Done")
            if ff > 0:
                good_el[ff] = i

        print(max(good_el.keys()),"\t",good_el[max(good_el.keys())].string)
        new_pop.clear_generation()
        while len(new_pop.generation) < 1000:
            parents = random.choices(list(good_el.values()),weights=list(good_el.keys()),k=2)
            new_element = crossover(parents[0],parents[1])
            mutate(new_element)
            new_pop.generation.append(new_element)
```

Comment: мало информации, разверните описание, примеры входных и пр., чтобы можно воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: Ошибки как таковой нет. Есть просто долгий поиск решения, причем на последнем символе. Это может быть любой символ фразы, а не конкретно последний знак.